# Finding The Correct File Path For a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, directory, filepath, event-viewer

So i have been working on this script at home

```
    Copy-Item "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx" "C:\CommFiles\LogFile_$(get-date -uformat %d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S).evtx"
if(-not $?) { 
Write-Warning "Copy Failed" 
} else {
Remove-Item "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"
}
```

and i know it works because i used it at home and it has the same file path that i use in office but i keep getting this warning

```
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx" "C:\Co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

i suspect that im not in the right directory but because of my limited knowledge on powershell im uncertain of what the right one might be for my case. im using this script to copy my event viewer log to a new file path for organised

Comment: What PowerShell and OS version is running on the machine with the issue?

Comment: @AdminOfThings this machine is running the most current version of PowerShell as far as i can tell and the OS version is windows 10 enterprise 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Comment: If you manually go into folder `C:\windows\System32\Winevt\Logs`, can you then see the `Security.evtx` file. Do you permissions allow you to copy it?

Comment: @Theo i have admin permissions but it doesnt matter and i used the solution below to get the correct file path and it does the same thing still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path can be found with the following steps:

1. Open Event Viewer as an administrator or a user with permission to view the security log.
2. Right-click the security log object on the left and open Properties.

[image: SecurityLog]

Or you can get the full path with powershell by checking the registry - note that this also requires running powershell as an admin user:

```
PS C:\> (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security\).file

C:\WINDOWS\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
```

Since your error specifically says `DirectoryNotFound`, try and find which directory it fails to open:

```
gci C:\
gci C:\windows\
gci C:\windows\System32\
gci C:\windows\System32\Winevt\
gci C:\windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\
```

And investigate the permissions on it:

```
(get-acl C:\Windows\System32\winevt\).Access | select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights

IdentityReference                FileSystemRights
-----------------                ----------------
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Read, Synchronize
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM              FullControl
BUILTIN\Administrators           FullControl
NT SERVICE\EventLog              DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
```

If everything seems fine there, consider trying the same thing on a different PC? I've had filesystem/harddrive issues that behaved like this, but it's not very likely

Comment: this only confirms that my file path is correct, idk why it still wont work. i have full admin privileges and i have powershell running as an admin. i still need more help.

Comment: @Zizzay I've added some further suggestions - hope this helps

Comment: so i was able to come to the conclusion that the folder i wanted to place the copied file into didnt exist yet. im not sure why but on my home desktop it created the folder and populated it all within this same exact code but now that the copy function works as intended again my remove function at the end still doesnt work.    Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx' because it is being used by another process.
At line:4 char:7

Comment: @Zizzay you will probably have to stop the event logging service: `stop-service eventlog`. In PSv5.1, you can do `Clear-EventLog Security` instead. I'm not sure what the goal is, but I would recommend changing the max size and roll-over properties in event viewer instead in most cases.

Comment: if i end the task would i have to start a new action using powershell for it to record more events? the end goal is to have clear event logs for each day for auditing reasons

Comment: @Zizzay yes, the service will need to be running to record new events. 

It's hard without knowing more, but I recommend not clearing logs this way. Consider WEF (built-in windows event forwarding/collection) or simply setting it to 'Archive when full' and grab those eventlog files. It's too easy to delete logs and auditors hate gaps... You can always filter events by date later.

Comment: how would i go about doing that? is it an event viewer function? can i set it to copy the file for a scheduled time?

Comment: @Zizzay 'archive when full' is in Event Viewer > Security Log > Properties. It renames the existing log file to `Archive-[logname]-[Date].evtx` in the same folder (only when it's full), and starts a new one. It's just a way to make sure you have all your logs forever. If you want events for a specific time, you can query logs with `Wevtutil` for those times and save to a new .evtx file I guess. There's no good reason to split the actual log files up by day though - that kind of thing should be done on the reporting side.